# awk code to multiply given column by number in space separated file

Tags: awk

I have space separated file. I want to do some math operation on given column. e.g. I want to multiply column 2 by 1e6. I can use following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; } {print $1,$2=$2*1e6,$3,$4}' result.txt
```

My problem is my file may contain any number of columns. In this case, what should my `awk` command be? Let's say my file has 25 columns, and I want to multiply the 15th column by 100. How can I do this in `awk`?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. All you need is `print $15*100`. Please [edit] and clarify your problem. Can the file have different numbers of columns per line, so you don't always want to print `$15`? Is it that you don't know how to print the entire line without listing the fields?

Comment: `awk '{$15 *= 100} 1'`

Comment: @terdon I believe the question is how to deal with `print $1, ... $NF` when you don't know in advance the number of columns.

Comment: @SatoKatsura yes, it might be. Or it might be because the number of columns changes, let's see if the OP clarifies. In the meantime, you may as well post your comment as an answer if you like.

Comment: It's also confusing that the question title refers to a "space separated file" but the posted example uses `FS=","`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing all the fields you can print the whole line with `$0`.

This can work because we can *change* fields by assigning data to them

eg

```
$2=$2*100
```

will update the second field and leave the rest untouched:

```
% echo '1 2 3 4' | awk '{$2=$2*100; print $0}'
1 200 3 4
```

We can make this smaller by making use of defaults; eg `print` on its own will print `$0`

```
awk '{$2=$2*100; print}'
```

We can even make use of default actions:

```
awk '{$2=$2*100} 1'
```

But in general I recommend the longer version because it's easier for other people to read and understand; code maintainability is as important as conciseness:

```
awk '{$2=$2*100; print $0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the number of columns, you can just update the one you need in place, and `awk` will reassemble them:

```
awk '{ $15 *= 100 } 1' file.csv
```

But you can also use `NF` if you need to, say like this:

```
awk '{ $15 *= 100; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf(" %d", $i); print "\n" }' file.csv
```